# Android more than 80 views

Tags: android

I have a question regarding my warning. 
I started a couple of days ago with making my first android app. However today I came across the 'more than 80 views' warning. Because I had to create tables in my design, I had to use a lot of different views to make these tables as you can see in my XML code. I did search for quite some time but I can't seem to find the right solution for my problem. I do consider using fragments on the activity itself, however I'm not sure if this will be the right solution for me. I'll hope you can push me in the right direction, thanks!

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/headingName_rideheight"
            style="@style/textHeadingStyle"/>
    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#ffff3bb2"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/rideheight_en"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageDescription_rideheight"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/subheadingName_overview"
            style="@style/textSubheadingStyle"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/summary_rideheight"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            style="@style/textSummaryStyle"/>
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ride_height_summary_expand_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/showMore"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_button_down"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageDescription_arrow_button"/>
    </TableRow>
    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffff3bb2"/>
    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#ffff3bb2"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/subheadingNameEffects_rideheight"
            style="@style/textSubheadingStyle"/>
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/table_layout_border"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TableRow
                style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
            <TextView
                    android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight"
                    style="@style/tableContentStyle_2"/>
            <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#ff000000"/>

            <TableLayout
                    style="@style/contentTableLayoutStyle">
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight_2"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight_3"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </TableRow>
        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#ff000000"/>
        <TableRow
                style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
            <TextView
                    android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight_4"
                    style="@style/tableContentStyle_2"/>
            <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#ff000000"/>

            <TableLayout
                    style="@style/contentTableLayoutStyle">
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight_5"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight_t6"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </TableRow>
        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#ff000000"/>
        <TableRow
                style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
            <TextView
                    android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight_7"
                    style="@style/tableContentStyle_2"/>
            <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#ff000000"/>
            <TableLayout
                    style="@style/contentTableLayoutStyle">
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight_8"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight_9"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight_10"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </TableRow>
        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#ff000000"/>
        <TableRow
                style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
            <TextView
                    android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight_11"
                    style="@style/tableContentStyle_2"/>
            <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#ff000000"/>
            <TableLayout
                    style="@style/contentTableLayoutStyle">
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight_12"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight_13"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight_14"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentEffects_rideheight_15"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffff3bb2"/>
    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#ffff3bb2"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/subheadingNameMeasuring_rideheight"
            style="@style/textSubheadingStyle"/>
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/table_layout_border"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TableRow
                style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
            <TextView
                    android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_initial_steps"
                    style="@style/tableContentStyle_3"/>
            <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#ffffffff"/>
            <TextView
                    android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_setup_components"
                    style="@style/tableContentStyle_3"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
                style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
            <TextView
                    android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_prepare_car"
                    style="@style/tableContentStyle_2"/>
            <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#ff000000"/>
            <TextView
                    android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_use_setup_components"
                    style="@style/tableContentStyle_2"/>
        </TableRow>
        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#ff000000"/>
        <TableRow
                style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
            <TableLayout
                    style="@style/contentTableLayoutStyle">
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_rideheight"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_rideheight_2"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_rideheight_3"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_rideheight_4"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
            <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#ff000000"/>

            <TableLayout
                    style="@style/contentTableLayoutStyle">
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_rideheight_5"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="•"
                            style="@style/tableContentDotStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_rideheight_6"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TableRow
                style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
            <TableLayout
                    style="@style/contentTableLayoutStyle_2">
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="1."
                            style="@style/tableContentNumberStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_rideheight_7"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle_4"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
                    <TextView
                            android:text="2."
                            style="@style/tableContentNumberStyle"
                            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_rideheight_8"
                            style="@style/tableContentStyle_4"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ride_height_step_1_2"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/imageDescription_rideheight_2"/>
        </TableRow>
        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="#ff000000"/>
        <TableRow
                style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
            <TableRow
                    style="@style/contentTableRowStyle_2">
                <TextView
                        android:text="3."
                        style="@style/tableContentNumberStyle"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                <TextView
                        android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_rideheight_9"
                        style="@style/tableContentStyle_4"/>
            </TableRow>
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ride_height_step_3"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/imageDescription_rideheight_3"/>
        </TableRow>
        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="#ff000000"/>
        <TableRow
                style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
            <TableRow
                    style="@style/contentTableRowStyle_2">
                <TextView
                        android:text="4."
                        style="@style/tableContentNumberStyle"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                <TextView
                        android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_rideheight_10"
                        style="@style/tableContentStyle_4"/>
            </TableRow>
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ride_height_step_4"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/imageDescription_rideheight_4"/>
        </TableRow>
        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="#ff000000"/>
        <TableRow
                style="@style/contentTableRowStyle">
            <TableRow
                    style="@style/contentTableRowStyle_2">
                <TextView
                        android:text="5."
                        style="@style/tableContentNumberStyle"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
                <TextView
                        android:text="@string/tableContentMeasuring_rideheight_11"
                        style="@style/tableContentStyle_4"/>
            </TableRow>
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ride_height_step_5"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/imageDescription_rideheight_5"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffff3bb2"/>
    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#ffff3bb2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This code results in this preview:![enter image description here][1]

http://foto.modelbouwforum.nl/images/2014/07/17/screenshot.png

Comment: How big is your display? :D

Answer (score 0):

I would either use fragments or if that content is static, maybe html..  you should also reconsider the design maybe.. If your scroll view is that long and just instructions it might not be the most usable interface to us a scrollView.  Perhaps a ViewPager, or tabs.